# How can I have resultset rows be shown as columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My table `price_matrix` is

```
id service_id  deadline  edu_level paper_stand  price
------------------------------------------------------
1     5         20         GCES       A          50
2     5         10         GCSE       A          30
3     5         20         GCSE       B          10
2     5         10         GCSE       B          40
```

How can I write a query that would give me result in following format

```
deadline   service_id   paper_stand A   paper_stand B edu_level
-----------------------------------------------------------------
20            5              50               10          GCES 
10            5              30                40          GCSE
```

The query I am using is

```
SELECT `paper_stand` , `deadline` , `price`
FROM `price_matrix`
WHERE `edu_level` = 'GCSE/ A Levels' && `service_id` =5
ORDER BY `paper_stand` , `deadline`
```

I am using MYSQL

Can anyone help me explain how I can get the result in desired format?

Thanks

Comment: It's called "pivot". Syntax varies depending on RDBMS, but you should be able to Google it.

Comment: You haven't really specified what you're grouping by.  I assume there can only ever be paper stand A and B - no others.  In that case are you grouping by deadline, service ID and edu level?  These are the things your pivot operator will need to know.  Generally it's a LOT easier to do this sort of manipulation in your display layer, whether that be a report, webpage or application.

Comment: what is the deadline value supposed to be ? is it max or min of deadline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the table to itself.

```
SELECT a.deadline,
       a.service_id,
       a.price AS paper_stand_a,
       b.price AS paper_stand_b,
       a.edu_level
FROM price_matrix AS a JOIN price_matrix AS b
    ON a.deadline = b.deadline AND a.paper_stand = 'A' AND b.paper_stand = 'B'
GROUP BY a.deadline;
```

You may also be able to do this without a join. I use `MAX` just to get a non NULL value for the price. There is probably a better way to do that part.

```
SELECT deadline,
       service_id,
       MAX(IF(paper_stand = 'A', price, NULL) AS paper_stand_a,
       MAX(IF(paper_stand = 'B', price, NULL) AS paper_stand_b,
       edu_level
FROM price_matrix
GROUP BY deadline;
```

Comment: Loved the way you joined [+1] (Y); I guess you need to add the Distinct or Group By to filter out the duplicate records.

Comment: @user1516790 did you figure it out, or is there still a problem? which one of these are you trying?

Answer (score 0):

We can use Inner Query on the select to acquire the result.

I do not have the SQL query builder but writing the query that would give you an idea.

```
SELECT deadline, service_id, edu_level,
       (SELECT price FROM price_matrix tmp 
        WHERE pm.deadline = tmp.deadline 
          AND pm.service_id = tmp.service_id
          AND tmp.paper_stand = 'A') AS PaperStandA,
       (SELECT price FROM price_matrix tmp 
        WHERE pm.deadline = tmp.deadline 
          AND pm.service_id = tmp.service_id
          AND tmp.paper_stand = 'B') AS PaperStandB,
FROM price_matrix pm
GROUP BY deadline, service_id, edu_level
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT A.deadline, A.edu_level, A.service_id, A.price as paper_standA, B.price as paper_standB
FROM (

SELECT *
FROM price_matrix
WHERE paper_stand = 'A'
) AS a, (

SELECT *
FROM price_matrix
WHERE paper_stand = 'B'
) AS b
WHERE a.service_id = b.service_id
AND b.deadline = a.deadline
```